# Запись в базу новых input

Tags: php, html, laravel

Подскажите пример кода на laravel.
В форме 4 поля для ввода, мне нужно каким то образом записать введеные данные в базу, то есть в базе должны создаться 4 записи

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" onsubmit="send()">
    <input type="text" class="guests-input" placeholder="Введите имя гостя">
    <input type="text" class="guests-input" placeholder="Введите имя гостя">
    <input type="text" class="guests-input" placeholder="Введите имя гостя">
    <input type="text" class="guests-input" placeholder="Введите имя гостя">
<input value="Отправить" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: где код на php? Где код на js?

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос я уверен что у Вас есть соответствующие route и  controller, а также таблица БД имеет либо один столбец (исключая автоматические столбцы типа id) либо остальные столбцы имеют дефолтные значения!)

**Замени**

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" onsubmit="send()">
```

на

```
<form action="{{route('names')}}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formx" onsubmit="send()> @csrf
```

**Добавь** в свои input поле name по примеру:

```
<input type="text" class="guests-input" placeholder="Введите имя гостя" name="name1">
```

**И в заключении создай** метод контроллера:

```
public function createNames(Request $request)
{     $name1 = new Names; // создание экземпляра класса
      $name1->name = $request->name1; // задаём значение имени в поле имя таблицы
      $name1->save(); // сохраняем результат и далее по примеру
      ...
}
```